# How to include all files in a folder in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

In Jekyll you can include a file by doing:

```
{% include some-folder/some-file.html %}
```

If you add more files to the folder you have to manually add them:

```
{% include some-folder/some-file-2.html %}
{% include some-folder/some-file-3.html %}
{% include some-folder/some-file-4.html %}
```

Is there a way in Jekyll to include all files in a folder automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible to have a variable name in an include ([source](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#using-variables-names-for-the-include-file)).

If this is allowed:

```
{% include {{ page.my_variable }} %}
```

Then also this is allowed:

```
{% include include_all_files.html folder="some-folder" %}
```

With an include_all_files.html that looks like this:

```
{% for file in site.static_files %}
  {% if file.path contains include.folder %}
    {% include {{ file.path }} %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Unfortunarely `site.static_files` doesn't include files with front matter, files in the `_includes` folder, or files that have been excluded in the `_config.yml` with `exclude:`.

Comment: Would what @JoostS describes work if you put all the relevant files into a collection and iterated over the collection rather than over site.static_files?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to include the content of all files in the current folder not including the current file.

```
{% assign parent_path = page.path | split:'/' | last %}
{% assign parent_path = page.path | remove:  parent_path %}

{% for file in site.static_files %}
{% if file.path contains parent_path %}
{% assign file_name = file.path | remove:  parent_path | remove:  "/" %}

{% include_relative {{ file_name }} %}

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Reason for my setup:** I have a large markdown file (`main.md`) that contains a lot of information, so I needed a way to move the content into separate files and included them with `main.md`.

Comment: Could anyone look into this?